# Changing language in UWP doesn't change system features language - only on app restart

Tags: xaml, localization, uwp

I have a UWP application.

And i have a need to change locale on the fly, so i have this for language changing:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language.FourDigitCode;
ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
```

**But there is a problem that system features language doesn't switch ( only after application relaunch ) how can i fix it?**

Here is an example:

[image]

Now i run this code:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "lv-LV";
ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
ResourceContext.GetForCurrentView();
```

The UI gets localized, but system features still remain unlocalized:

[image]

But when i restart the app, all is OK:

[image]

**Any ideas how can i fix it?**

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there is no fix for this and what you've seen is by design. Ref **Remarks** of [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages#Windows_Globalization_ApplicationLanguages_PrimaryLanguageOverride) property:

> When you set the [PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages#Windows_Globalization_ApplicationLanguages_PrimaryLanguageOverride), this is immediately reflected in the [Languages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages#Windows_Globalization_ApplicationLanguages_Languages) property. However, this change may not take effect immediately on resources loaded in the app UI. To make sure the app responds to such changes, you can listen to the [QualifierValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext#Windows_ApplicationModel_Resources_Core_ResourceContext_QualifierValues) property on a default resource context and take whatever actions may be needed to reload resources. Those requirements may vary depending on the UI framework used by the app, and **it may be necessary to restart the app**.

For your scenario, a restart is needed. I'd suggest that you can add a tip to tell users to restart the app and also a button to close the app like what used in News App.
[image]
And to close the app, we can call [Application.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Application#Windows_UI_Xaml_Application_Exit) method like the following.

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```

Comment: Jea, but thats not cool... maybe there is another option to localize the app and also the system features without reloading the app?

Comment: @Cheese AFAIK, there is no other option for your scenario. A restart is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe page reloading can fix it? Try to re-navigate to the same page.
Found the example below [here](http://www.guruumeditation.net/en/dynamically-change-the-language-of-a-universal-app/).

```
//like this
private bool Reload(object param = null)
{
    var type = Frame.CurrentSourcePageType; 
    Frame.Navigate(type, param);
    Frame.BackStack.Remove(Frame.BackStack.Last());
}

// or like this
private bool Reload(object param = null)
{
    var frame = Window.Current.Content as Frame; 
    frame.Navigate(frame.CurrentSourcePageType, param);
    frame.BackStack.Remove(frame .BackStack.Last());
}
```