# ToggleSwitch default oncontent/offcontent text does not get translated at runtime

Tags: c#, resources, uwp, toggleswitch

In my app, users can switch the language at runtime like this:

```
Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = language;
```

The ResourceContext also gets reset after that:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.Core.ResourceContext.GetForViewIndependentUse().Reset();
```

The problem is that everything gets translated directly except for the default toggleswitch OnContent & OffContent text ("on" & "off").

Can this be solved without restarting the app and without creating text resources for each ToggleSwitch in my project?

Comment: Have you tried to Re-navigate to the current page to refresh the UI by `Frame.Navigate(this.GetType());`

Comment: I did that :) . the toggleswitch problem is not only on the page where the user can change the language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing language in UWP doesn't change system features language - only on app restart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42859407/changing-language-in-uwp-doesnt-change-system-features-language-only-on-app-r)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42899051/2271150), Jay Zuo already stated that in the comments.

Since the default behavior of the ToggleSwitch will not reflect the language change at runtime I came around this by writing a converter which gets the language specific translation from the ResourceLoader and binding the `OnContent` and `OffContent` properties of the ToggleSwitch to its `IsOn` property. You have to provide the translations for "On" and "Off" texts in your language specific resource string files.

Converter:

```
class BoolToToggleSwitchOnOffContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        if (value is bool boolValue)
        {
            var resourceLoader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
            var resourceString = "ToggleSwitch" + (boolValue ? "On" : "Off");
            return resourceLoader.GetString(resourceString);
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        // I'm afraid I can't do that, Dave!
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ToggleSwitch
            IsOn="{Binding SomeIsOnBinding, Mode=TwoWay}"
            OnContent="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToToggleSwitchOnOffContentConverter}"
            OffContent="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToToggleSwitchOnOffContentConverter}" />
```